# How to bind to ColumnCollection for a GridView using XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding, gridview

I have a collection of objects which I would like to represent columns in a GridView.
Currently I am binding individual columns in my GridView to items in the collection like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Path=MyColumns[0].Title}"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Path=MyColumns[1].Title}"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Path=MyColumns[2].Title}"></GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

This works well, but what I really want to do is to bind to the collection itself (since the number of items in the collection might change at run-time).  I would like to accomplish this in XAML.  What I have in mind is something like this (note this does not work - the ColumnsSource attribute is make-believe):

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView ColumnsSource="{Binding Path=MyColumns}">
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: I found a duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/q/1863200/503969 but the wording and presentation is quite different.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [attached property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.100).aspx) to create a `ColumnsSource` property, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385129/window-inputbindings-with-a-bound-collection) for an example.

Comment: @GregSansom: No, i am not talking about `ItemsSource`. You do not seem to have understood my point, see the question i linked to...