# Window.InputBindings with a bound collection

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, collections, key-bindings

I can't find anything that looks like this online. I am looking for a way to create a collection of Keybindings in the code (with a Keybinding ViewModel), and then bind the collection to the view, instead of listing out every binding manually in Xaml.

I would expect it to look something like this

```
<Window.InputBindings ItemsSource="{Binding Path=KeybindingList}" />
```

and then in the code, have a List. Is such an approach possible? Where would I start?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx), listen to its changes and modify the `InputBindings` collection of the associated window.

An example:

```cs
// Snippet warning: This may be bad code, do not copy.
public static class AttachedProperties
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputBindingsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
            (
                "InputBindingsSource",
                typeof(IEnumerable),
                typeof(AttachedProperties),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(null, InputBindingsSource_Changed)
            );
    public static IEnumerable GetInputBindingsSource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (IEnumerable)obj.GetValue(InputBindingsSourceProperty);
    }
    public static void SetInputBindingsSource(DependencyObject obj, IEnumerable value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(InputBindingsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    private static void InputBindingsSource_Changed(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uiElement = obj as UIElement;
        if (uiElement == null)
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Object of type '{0}' does not support InputBindings", obj.GetType()));

        uiElement.InputBindings.Clear();
        if (e.NewValue == null)
            return;

        var bindings = (IEnumerable)e.NewValue;
        foreach (var binding in bindings.Cast<InputBinding>())
            uiElement.InputBindings.Add(binding);
    }
}
```

This can be used on any `UIElement`:

```
<TextBox ext:AttachedProperties.InputBindingsSource="{Binding InputBindingsList}" />
```

If you want it to be very fancy you can type-check for [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) and update the `InputBindings` if the collection changes but you will need to unsubscribe from the old collection and such so you need to be more careful with that.

Comment: To modify the window, you would need to do this in the code-behind, right? I am trying to do this to keep in the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @Tyrsius: It's not in the code of the window, it can be in any class, it's like using a value converter in a binding, has nothing to do with MVVM.

Comment: @Tyrsius: I added an example to illustrate the approach.