# How to do InputBindings for a DataBound ListBox?

Tags: wpf, commandbinding

I have a `ListBox` with `ItemsSource` bound. If anyone selects a `ListBoxItem` and presses Enter key, a  command should be executed. How could I do this? I have `ItemContainerStyle` for `ListBox` and I cannot find a way to set `InputBindings` through Style.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an attached helper property which sets the bindings, [here would be an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385129/window-inputbindings-with-a-bound-collection/9385191#9385191), you then can set that property in the style.